# Differential Geometry - Inverse is continuous

Tags: differential-geometry

In the book Differential Geometry of Curve and Surfaces - Manfredo Do Carmo, there is the following proposition:

Let $p \in S$ be a point of a regular surface $S$ and let $X: U \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^3$ be a map with $p \in X(U)$ such that $X$ is differentiable, one-to-one and the jacobian transformation is injective. So, $X^{-1}$ is continuous.

I didn't see where is used the assumption of $p$ belongs to $S$. Can someone tell me where it is used?

[image: The proof from Manfredo's book]

Comment: You forgot the assumption that the image of X is contained in S. The point p is indeed irrelevant. What you need to know is the inverse mapping theorem for smooth maps.

Comment: In the book, the statement is exactly how I wrote. Anyway, reading the proof, seems to me that we can throw away the regular surface, but we can't. Why?

Comment: Because otherwise the statement is wrong. See if you can find an example of an injective smooth map of the open interval to the plane which has injective derivative and discontinuous inverse.

Comment: Yes, I already did that. My question was: where is used the fact $X(U) \subset S$ in the proof.

Comment: I have no idea what the proof in the book is. (The proof that I would give is based on inverse function theorem for maps between open planar sets. To reduce the problem to the IFT it is critical that the target is a surface.)You should copy the proof from the book to your question.

Answer (score 0):

$X^{-1}$ is defined only in the image set...